# How to disable onclick event on large screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have this onclick event work only on mobile devices. When you click on this element it moves to the anchor (#map) on the page. How can I disable it on large screens?

```
<span 
onclick="document.location=document.location.toString().split('#') 
[0]+'#map';return false;">
</span>
```

Comment: Add class or id to the span tag and use the script in script tag or .js file, where you can get window.innerWidth through which you can check if less than 320 i.e., baisc mobile devices width and add click listener if it satisfies condition

Answer (score 3):

Have a named function where you can add more instructions easily... Like an `if` condition.

```
<span 
onclick="myFunctionName();">
</span>

<script>
function myFunctionName(){
  if(window.innerWidth<768){
    document.location=document.location.toString().split('#')[0]+'#map';
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

[Here](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) are the *common* breakpoints used to determine how to display a page.

I suggest less than 768px to make sure to include all mobiles, but that's up to you to evaluate that. ;)